# How to let mysql return the row with highest bullishness value?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

Consider the following table:

```
stock    _date       return2  bullishness
-----------------------------------------
1        2011-03-14  0.10     0.75
2        2011-03-14  0.05     1.75
3        2011-03-14  0.11     1.00
1        2011-03-15  0.03     1.99
2        2011-03-15  0.30     4.00
3        2011-03-15  0.00     0.60
```

I'm looking for a query which will:

- look at the `bullishness` for all `stock`s for a specific `_date`
- and return the row with the highest `bullishness`

I would have expected, for `2011-03-14` to accomplish this with

```
SELECT MAX(bullishness) as bullishness, stock, return2 
FROM stocks 
WHERE _date = '2011-03-14'
```

But this just always returns the first row, in this case:

```
1   2011-03-14  0.10  0.75
```

While I would have expected the query to return the second row (since it has a `bullishness` of 1.75, which is higher then 0.75):

```
2   2011-03-14  0.05  1.75
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would just use ORDER BY bullishness and select the top row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) like `MAX()` do not work the way you expect them to work.

You could use this trick to get what you want:

```
SELECT bullishness, stock, return2 
FROM stocks 
WHERE _date = '2011-03-14'
ORDER BY bullishness DESC
LIMIT 1
```

You are basically ordering by bullishness descending, so the biggest bullishness comes first. Then you are limiting to only one result.